# Get ErrorInternalServerTransientError when querying outlook rest api

Tags: outlook-api

i get Get ErrorInternalServerTransientError when querying outlook rest api:

> "code":"ErrorInternalServerTransientError","message":"An internal
>   server error occurred. Try again later."

I have got the access token,how to solve it

Comment: Same here but it happens only with some users, other users work fine.

Comment: Actually, oauth works fine for these accounts but setting up Webhook subscription fails.  It appears to have something to do with certain types of Microsoft accounts.  Office365 accounts with Exchange work fine.

Comment: I updated the answer as the fix has been deployed worldwide.  Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

We have investigated this issue and are working on a fix.  You should be receiving a 404 error with code "UserNotEnabledForRESTAPI" in this case as the user's outlook.com account hasn't yet been enabled for Outlook RETS APIs.  Sorry for the inconvenience.  I will update this post when the fix is deployed.

UPDATE: This fix is now deployed worldwide and you shouldn't see this error.

Comment: Thank you , waiting for the fix .